# Is there a way to animate a point along a path in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I've drawn a chart (like a path) and now want to animate either another element, like a line or a point to trace along it is there a way to do this?

Edit 1:
Adding in more details to explain what I want to achieve:
[image: Image of the graph] Imaging this being the plot of some values in black using chart.js (Im not personally tied to this library but its what I'm using right now if you have better solutions then please feel free to suggest any)
I want a line to be animated along it - the red line, with the little red circle to go up and down along the values corresponding to the plot. I want this animation to loop, pause and rewind based on some other parameters or buttons that I set up in the window. More making interacting with this data easier.

Comment: Yes, there is. You may start by looking at the docs on [animations](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animations) and also at the [samples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/animations/delay.html). To get a useful answer here, please share your code and make your question more precise, possibly by adding an image, to describe what exactly do you want to move, on what path and for how long (loop forever or a limited interval).

Comment: Hello! So Ive added in a picture and a more detailed explanation of what I want to do - hope this helps clarify what I want to do! Thanks!